# Is it safe to run GET requests to potentially extremist URLs from inside a Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, security, get, malware

I have a Python script that grabs a list of URLs from a MySQL table, then attempts to GET the title from each site, before writing the result to another MySQL table.

The URLs nominally link to extremist content (eg supremacist tweets, blogs, etc).  The purpose of the above setup is to determine if a given link is still live, or if it has been suspended / died.  The script runs regularly.

I currently have all of this setup in Docker containers **inside** a Linux VM.  My concern is that there is theoretically a malware risk from one of the sites pinged.

Is this overkill?  How much of a risk would there be of malware backwash into a Docker container from a GET request in the first place, and from the container into the host system?

Thanks, and apologies for my rudimentary networks / infosec knowledge.

Comment: If you just want to know if the site is up or not you don't even need to parse the response content but cound use the response status code, if that is 200 the response is ok and the site still active.(if i understand your problem correctly)

Comment: Thanks for the response - unfortunately I do need to go a bit deeper, because Twitter, for example, will return a 200 even if the Twitter account has been suspended.  In that example, I would want to capture the Twitter page title (which is something specific, like 'Account suspended') ... 

But thanks!